# Display a range if a value is in the range else if value is less or greater than range display '$'

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have numeric data i want to code a generic macro to display a range if the numeric variable value is falling in the range else if value is less or greater than range range then display '$$$'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Format depends on whether age is a numeric or character variable. I have assumed numeric here, if it is character you need to add a $.

```
proc format;
value age_A
0-14 = '$$$'
15-25 = '15-25'
25-high = '$$$'
;run;
```

If you want to use this in a proc print/freq etc then use

```
proc print data = ;
var age;
format age age_a.;
run;
```

if you want to change the data in a dataset then use the put function.

```
data ;
set;
new_var = put(age, age_a.);
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a format to do this. Read up on defining formats with `proc format` [here](http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi27/p056-27.pdf) or look at the official documentation.

Comment: @Apache11 you don't need a macro.  As @user667489 suggests, create a format with `proc format`, then assign that format to the age variable.  Formatted values are displayed by default, even though the underlying values are not changed